# How to create a "floating", openable/closable button-containing Box composable drawn over existing composables?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

What I'm basically trying to achieve is having a button menu where some of the buttons trigger the showing of an additional menu that contains "sub-buttons". I don't want to use something like the DropdownMenu as I want to order the sub-buttons in a box with a column two-rows wide.

I tried consulting ChatGPT and while it offered a working solution with the DropdownMenu, trying to make it in the form mentioned above doesn't seem to work. The buttons that hold data for sub-buttons don't trigger any box overlay.

The code is probably quite messy and "incorrectly written", but either way I'm adding the relevant snippets hoping that someone has a solution:

A composable function that runs when the phone is in horizontal orientation which divides the screen into layout areas and fills them through other functions with buttons:

```
@Composable
fun LandscapeScreen() {
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    screenHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp
    screenWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp

    var rememberSelectedOption by remember { mutableStateOf(OpenCloseFloating.selectedOption) }
    var rememberExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(OpenCloseFloating.expanded) }
    var rememberHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(OpenCloseFloating.height) }
    var rememberButtonList by remember { mutableStateOf(OpenCloseFloating.buttonList) }

    BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()) {
//        Main divisions of screen layout
        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            LeftArea(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(1/8f))
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(0.dp))
            RightArea(Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
        }
//        Should provide a closable floating window with updating buttons
        LaunchedEffect(OpenCloseFloating.expanded) {
            rememberExpanded = OpenCloseFloating.expanded
            rememberHeight = OpenCloseFloating.height
            rememberButtonList = OpenCloseFloating.buttonList
            rememberSelectedOption = OpenCloseFloating.selectedOption
        }
        Box(Modifier.fillMaxHeight(rememberHeight).fillMaxWidth(1/8f)
            .background(Color.Cyan).clickable(enabled = true, onClick = {})
            .run {if (rememberExpanded) this else (Modifier)}) {
//            Should create an updatable button content within the box
            StaticButtonsColumn(
                buttonList = rememberButtonList,
                cornerRoundness = 8,
                fontSize = 10
            )
        }
    }
}
```

All of those remember variables were supposed to be able to trigger a recomposition when the parameters of this class update:

```
class OpenCloseFloating() {
    companion object{
        var selectedOption: String = "name"
        var expanded: Boolean = false
        var height: Float = 1f
        var buttonList: List<ButtonData> = listOf()
    }
}
```

Now, this is the function that creates the two-per-row arrangement of the buttons:

```
@Composable
private fun StaticButtonsColumn(buttonList: List<ButtonData>,
                            cornerRoundness: Int, fontSize: Int) {
    var index: Int = 0
    var buttonIndex: Int
    Column {
        while (index * 2 <= buttonList.lastIndex) {
            buttonIndex = index * 2
            Row {
                if (buttonIndex < buttonList.lastIndex) {
                    CreateButtons(
                        buttonData = buttonList[buttonIndex],
                        cornerRoundness = cornerRoundness,
                        fontSize = fontSize
                    )
                    if (buttonIndex+1 <= buttonList.lastIndex) {
                        CreateButtons(
                            buttonData = buttonList[buttonIndex+1],
                            cornerRoundness = cornerRoundness,
                            fontSize = fontSize
                        )
                    }
                    index += 1
                }
                else if (buttonIndex == buttonList.lastIndex) {
                    CreateButtons(
                        buttonData = buttonList[buttonIndex],
                        ratio = 2f,
                        cornerRoundness = cornerRoundness,
                        fontSize = fontSize
                    )
                    index += 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the function that creates the actual buttons:

```
@Composable
fun RowScope.CreateButtons(buttonData: ButtonData, ratio: Float = 1f, cornerRoundness: Int, fontSize: Int) {    
    if (!buttonData.hasSubButtons) {
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .aspectRatio(ratio)
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(1.dp),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(cornerRoundness.dp),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
            onClick = buttonData.onClick
        ) {
            Text(text = buttonData.name, fontSize = fontSize.sp, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        }
    }
    else {
        var selectedOption: String by remember { mutableStateOf(buttonData.name) }
        var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .aspectRatio(ratio)
                 .weight(1f)
                .padding(1.dp),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(cornerRoundness.dp),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
            onClick = { expanded = !expanded }
        ) {
            Text(text = selectedOption, fontSize = fontSize.sp, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        }    
        if (expanded) {
            OpenCloseFloating.selectedOption = selectedOption
            OpenCloseFloating.expanded = true
            OpenCloseFloating.buttonList = buttonData.subButtons
            OpenCloseFloating.height = if ((buttonData.subButtons.size/2f % 1) == 0.5f) ((buttonData.subButtons.size/2f) + 0.5f) else (buttonData.subButtons.size/2f)
        }
        else {
            OpenCloseFloating.expanded = false
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the object holding data about the button:

```
class ButtonData (val name: String, val onClick: () -> Unit,
                  val hasSubButtons: Boolean = false,
                  val subButtons: List<ButtonData> = listOf()) {
}
```

There are additional functions that construct lists of ButtonData for each appropriate button group within the layout.

So something must be wrong with the code within LandscapeScreen and/or CreateButtons.

(*I'm not sure selectedOption is doing something right now even theoretically, but in the earlier version with the DropdownMenu it did change the text of a main button to that of the option selected from the DropdownMenu)

Comment: not sure of your requirement. are you looking for this https://github.com/saket/cascade.? and this https://github.com/AndroidPoet/Dropdown

Comment: @Raghunandan Not for this particular case, although this is an interesting effect that I might be using in a different part elsewhere. For this particular case I need to have a box holding a column holding a row holding two buttons (per row), that is toggled visible and invisible according to the button pressed (one that holds subbuttons information) and that is "repopulated" with the appropriate buttons according to the button-with-subbuttons which was pressed.